# SOAP WS-Security header UsernameToken is element tenant valid?

Tags: soap, structure, ws-security, usernametoken

I've got a UsernameToken:

```
<wsse:UsernameToken>
  <tenant>myTenant</tenant>
  <wsse:Username>
    USER
  </wsse:Username>
  <wsse:Password Type="blabla"
     >PASSWORD
  </wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
```

Now I've googled a lot but couldn't find out, if the element `<tenant>` is a valid element for the wsse:UsernameToken. I've found informations about the [UsernameToken](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf) but there was no information about the tenant element.

My question is: Is this element valid and if yes, where can I find a specific declaration, how such a UsernameToken has to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd allows arbitrary elements under `UsernameToken`, so that looks like a custom extension. (Technically, `wsse:Username` should be first, so it probably won't validate, but semantically it's OK)

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. Is there an element which can be used the same way like the "tenant"-tag, but which isn't a custom extension?(To write into the soap which user is the tenant)

Comment: Doesn't look like it from the schema.

Comment: One last question. How can I check if such a structure allows arbitrary elements?

Comment: @c0dev look for `xs:any` type elements